# How do the "includes" and "excludes" operators work in Workflow rule criteria?

Tags: workflow, operators

Does anybody know how the "includes" and "excludes" operators work when setting up rule criteria for workflow rules?

The only documentation I've found on this is located at https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=filter_operators.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=204.14 - this is good documentation, but since it is filed under Reports & Dashboards I get a little uneasy that it might be inaccurate.

My understanding is that the "includes" and "excludes" operators are only available when the field you've chosen is a multi-select picklist field (as the documentation states). These operators seem to work similarly to the "equals" and "not equal to" operators, except that multi-select picklist values are stored in a semi-colon delimited string that is split into multiple values when the workflow rule does its evaluation.

I've done some testing and the results I'm seeing are different than what I was expecting, and the documentation doesn't make it very clear. So here we go:

### Working Scenario - "Includes"

From the documentation linked above:

> Available when you choose a multi-select picklist as the selected field. Use this operator to find records that include one or more of the values you enter.

There exists a custom multi-select picklist field (`Custom_Picklist__c`) on the Lead with the values: A, B, C, D.

There exists a custom checkbox field (`Checkbox__c`) on the Lead.

We create a Workflow rule that sets the `Checkbox__c` field to true every time a lead is created or edited and `Custom_Picklist__c includes A, C`

**Results:**

Lead #1: `Custom_Picklist__c = null` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Lead #2: `Custom_Picklist__c = B` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Lead #3: `Custom_Picklist__c = A` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #4: `Custom_Picklist__c = A; B; C` & `Checkbox__c = true`

All results evaluate as expected. The record only needs one of the values to be selected in order for the workflow to fire.

### Broken(?) Scenario - "Excludes"

From the documentation linked above:

> Available when you choose a multi-select picklist as the selected field. Use this operator to find records that do not contain any values that match the ones entered.

Same as above - `Custom_Picklist__c` & `Checkbox__c` custom fields exist on the Lead.

We create a Workflow rule that sets the `Checkbox__c` field to true every time a lead is created or edited and `Custom_Picklist__c excludes A, C`

**Results:**

Lead #1: `Custom_Picklist__c = null` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #2: `Custom_Picklist__c = B` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #3: `Custom_Picklist__c = A` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #4: `Custom_Picklist__c = A; B; C` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Results do *not* evaluate as expected. I did *not* expect to see Lead #3's checkbox field set to true. The workflow rule is set to only act on records where the multi-select excludes A, C - I expected that to mean that the record would be ignored even if only one of those values is selected.

Am I misunderstanding the documentation? Or did I find a workflow bug?

---

Edit: I did some more testing using multi-select picklists with "equals" and "not equal to" and so I wanted to share those results as well.

### Working Scenario - "Equals"

Same as above - `Custom_Picklist__c` & `Checkbox__c` custom fields exist on the Lead.

We create a Workflow rule that sets the `Checkbox__c` field to true every time a lead is created or edited and `Custom_Picklist__c equals A, C`

**Results:**

Lead #1: `Custom_Picklist__c = null` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Lead #2: `Custom_Picklist__c = B` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Lead #3: `Custom_Picklist__c = A` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #4: `Custom_Picklist__c = A; B; C` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Results are as expected, I guess. The "equals" operator is different than "includes" because Lead #4 evaluates to false. The picklist must *equal* A, C (or just A or just C) and cannot contain another other values.

### Broken(?) Scenario - "Not Equal To"

Same as above - `Custom_Picklist__c` & `Checkbox__c` custom fields exist on the Lead.

We create a Workflow rule that sets the `Checkbox__c` field to true every time a lead is created or edited and `Custom_Picklist__c not equal to A, C`

**Results:**

Lead #1: `Custom_Picklist__c = null` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #2: `Custom_Picklist__c = B` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #3: `Custom_Picklist__c = A` & `Checkbox__c = false`

Lead #4: `Custom_Picklist__c = A; B; C` & `Checkbox__c = true`

Lead #5: `Custom_Picklist__c = A; C` & `Checkbox__c = true`

This one blew my mind and I had to include even more results here because it's just damn confusing. If the picklist only has A selected or only has C selected, the workflow works as expected. I can maybe understand why it evaluates to true if A, B, and C are selected since B is not part of the not equal to criteria.

But A, C evaluates to true? How? Those are specifically the values I'm setting the criteria for not equal to.

Comment: I've opened a case with Salesforce around this and am waiting to hear what they say.

Answer (score 1):

**Salesforce's response to this issue (Case #15237638) is as follows:**

The multi-select picklist scenarios above are working as designed. They have submitted my feedback to the Knowledge team to update the documentation (as while it may be working as designed, I argued that it is certainly not working as documented).

**The following workaround can be taken to achieve better results:**

Wherever an 'AND' comparison is intended, the multi-pick list values should have their own lines in the criteria. Ex: If the workflow is intended to fire when *both* A & C are excluded, A & C should be in separate lines.

(I think they meant to say 'OR' comparison here, but I'm not entirely sure.)

I created an idea to hopefully gather upvotes in improving this feature - so if you feel this needs more attention, I would appreciate an upvote: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNJdQAM